# Find text value with =IMPORTXML and xPath including filter

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fetch

At this moment I'm starting to learn more and more on the importXML function for Google Sheets. I want to fetch some data from several open data pages but it is kinda hard since they didn't use attributes to easily find the information that you are looking for.

**URL to fetch:** https://opendata.nederlandwereldwijd.nl/v1/sources/nederlandwereldwijd/infotypes/traveladvice/a790e247-8ff8-4aa8-be93-9202ccaa180a

**xPath I used:** `/document/content/contentblock/paragraphtitle[contains(text(), "Veiligheidsrisico’s")]/summary`

**What I want to do:** I want the =importxml function to return the text within `<summary> </summary>` in the block where `<paragraphtitle>` = 'Veiligheidsrisico's'.

I hope that you can help me with this so I can continue learning and with my fetching work! :)

Kind regards,
Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to use [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) using **Google Apps Script**.

Click on **Tools** => **Script editor**:

[image: example]

**copy & paste** the following function to the code.gs file:

```
function parseXml() {
  
  var url = 'https://opendata.nederlandwereldwijd.nl/v1/sources/nederlandwereldwijd/infotypes/traveladvice/a790e247-8ff8-4aa8-be93-9202ccaa180a';
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  str = xml.split("<paragraphtitle>Veiligheidsrisico’s</paragraphtitle>")[1]
  mySubString = str.match(new RegExp("<summary>" + "(.*)" + "</summary>"))[1];
  
  return mySubString;
}
```

and then you can use that as a **formula**:

[image: formula]

**References:**

[XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

Comment: Cool this is interesting! But, since I use this to fetch data from different countries (different URL's) how can I change this in the script?

At this moment I've got the URL's in row A, the country names in row B and I want to get the text data (that we fetch) in row C. Is this also possible via the script or is it better to use the long formula in that case?

Comment: @SamiChouchane we can construct a more generic formula to accept as arguments URL and country or whatever. But this would be the topic of another question. Please post a new question if you want and I will be very much happy to answer it :) but yes, it is possible and maybe more preferable than formulas if you can find a generic pattern that works for different countries and URLs.

Comment: Great, thanks Marios. I will create a new post. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer myself. Just changed the code to: `/document/content/contentblock[paragraphtitle='Veiligheidsrisico’s']/summary` and it seems to work :)